# Service consume mucha RAM

Tags: android

He creado un pequeño service de notificaciones para mi aplicación en el que te avisa si ese día tienes un evento programado.

Este service lo que hace es consultar en una pequeña base de datos Sqlite, si ese día hay alguna nota guardada y si es así te manda un NotificationManager. Esta operación me llega a consumir hasta 98Mb de memoria RAM con la consecuente eliminación por parte de android, quedandose el service activo con 4,5MB pero sin realizar la tarea que tenia prevista.

El service está programado para que recargue la comprobación cada minuto para que cuando llegue la hora programada por el usuario para que le lance las notificaciones lo haga.

No se si necesitáis que os incluya algo de código para ver algo en concreto y me podáis echar una mano con este problemilla.

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

Este es el lanzamiento del servicio

```
private void LanzarAvisoNotificacion(){

    Equipo = EquipoLayout;
    EquipoJunto = EquipoJuntoLayout;
    mes = MesLayout;
    ServicioActivado = 1;
    PrimeraNotificacion = 1;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Meses.this, ServicioNotificaciones.class);
    if (ServicioActivadoLayout == 0){
        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("Activado el servicio de notificación del "+ Equipo);

    }
    intent.putExtra("mes",mes);
    intent.putExtra("mesLetra", MesLetra);
    intent.putExtra("dia", DiaLayout);
    intent.putExtra("dianulo", dianulo);
    intent.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemana);
    intent.putExtra("Equipo", Equipo);
    intent.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJunto);
    intent.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivado);
    intent.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacion);
    intent.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
    intent.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(Meses.this, 1234567, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 59, sender);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Este es el código del servicio

```
public class ServicioNotificaciones extends Service {

private int i = 1;
//private String PrimeraNotificacionServicio;
public String mesLetraServicio;
public int mesServicio;
public int diaServicio;
public int dianuloServicio;
public int diaSemanaServicio;
public String EquipoServicio;
public String EquipoJuntoServicio;
public int ServicioActivadoServicio;
public int NotificacionLanzadaServicio;
private String mesletraServicio;
private Integer mesnotificacion;
private int ContaNotificaciones;
private int PrimeraNotificacionServicio;
private int AlarmaConectadaServicio;



private String equiponotificacion;
private int HoraNotificacion;
private int MinutoNotificacion;
public Notas[] datosLista;
public ControlNotas usdbh;
private boolean isRunning = false;
private String mesnotificacionletra;

private int DiaSer;
private int MesSer;
private int MesSer1;
private String MesSerLetra;
private int hora;
private int minuto;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    isRunning = true;

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {



    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DiaSer = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    MesSer = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    MesSer1 = MesSer + 1;
    hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    mesnotificacion = MesSer1;
    ComprobarMesPequeño();

    mesServicio = intent.getIntExtra("mes", 0);
    mesLetraServicio = intent.getStringExtra("mesLetra");
    diaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("dia", 0);
    dianuloServicio = intent.getIntExtra("dianulo", 0);
    diaSemanaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("diaSemana", 0);
    EquipoServicio = intent.getStringExtra("Equipo");
    EquipoJuntoServicio = intent.getStringExtra("EquipoJunto");
    ServicioActivadoServicio = intent.getIntExtra("ServicioActivado", 0);
    PrimeraNotificacionServicio = intent.getIntExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", 0);
    AlarmaConectadaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", 0);
    NotificacionLanzadaServicio = intent.getIntExtra("notificacionlanzada", 0);


    if (ContaNotificaciones == 1) {
        PrimeraNotificacionServicio = 1;
    }

    //Creating new thread for my service
    //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBControlNotificacion' en modo escritura
            ControlNotificacion cont = new ControlNotificacion(getApplicationContext(), "DBControlNotificacion.sqlite", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = cont.getReadableDatabase();

            String cod = "1";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT equipo, horanotificacion, minutonotificacion FROM ControlNotificacion where codigo=" + cod , null);



            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String equ = c.getString(0);
                int hora = c.getInt(1);
                int minuto = c.getInt(2);

                equiponotificacion = equ;
                HoraNotificacion = hora;
                MinutoNotificacion = minuto;


                db.close();
                c.close();

            }

                if (hora == HoraNotificacion && minuto == MinutoNotificacion){

                //Abrimos la base de datos 'DBUsuarios' en modo escritura
                usdbh = new ControlNotas(ServicioNotificaciones.this, "DBnotas" + equiponotificacion + ".sqlite", null, 1);

                db = usdbh.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor ConsultaNotas = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM 'notas' " +
                        "WHERE diames='" + DiaSer + "'" +
                        "AND mesmes='" + mesnotificacionletra + "'", null);

                if (ConsultaNotas.moveToFirst()) {
                    //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                    datosLista = new Notas[ConsultaNotas.getCount()];
                    int i = 0;
                    do {
                        datosLista[i] = new Notas();
                        datosLista[i].setDiames(ConsultaNotas.getInt(0));
                        datosLista[i].setMesmes(ConsultaNotas.getString(1));
                        datosLista[i].setNota(ConsultaNotas.getString(2));
                        i++;
                    } while (ConsultaNotas.moveToNext());

                    db.close();

                    if (isRunning) {
                        // Preparamos el intent que será lanzado si la notificación es seleccionada
                        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ServicioNotificaciones.this, Meses.class);
                        NotificacionLanzadaServicio = 1;
                        intent.putExtra("mes",mesServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("mesLetra", mesLetraServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("dia", diaServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacionServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaServicio);
                        intent.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", NotificacionLanzadaServicio);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ServicioNotificaciones.this, 0, intent, 0);

                        // Creamos la notificación.
                        CharSequence ticker = "Aviso de Nota";
                        CharSequence contentTitle = "Calendario Sevilla";
                        CharSequence contentText = "Tienes una nueva nota para hoy";
                        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ServicioNotificaciones.this)
                                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                .setTicker(ticker)
                                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                                .setContentText(contentText)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icono_aplicacion_pequeno)
                                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                                .setSound(soundUri)
                                .build();
                        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        // Ocultamos la notificación si ha sido ya seleccionada
                        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



                        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

                    }


                }

            }

        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    isRunning = false;
    stopSelf();

}
```

Aqui os dejo la clase ControNotas.

```
public class ControlNotas extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



String sql = "CREATE TABLE notas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, diames INTEGER, mesmes TEXT, nota TEXT, equipo TEXT)";


public ControlNotas(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}




@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnte, int versionNue) {

}

public void InsertarUsuario (SQLiteDatabase db, Integer diames, String mesmes, String nota, String equipo){

    SQLiteStatement pat = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO notas (diames, mesmes, nota, equipo) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    pat.bindLong(1, diames);
    pat.bindString(2, mesmes);
    pat.bindString(3, nota);
    pat.bindString(4, equipo);
    pat.execute();
}
```

}

Comment: Si,definitivamente necesitamos ver el código, ¿Puedes poner el código del servicio en sí por favor?

Comment: Que realiza ControlNotas() ???

Comment: ControlNotas() es el que controla la base de datos, o sea el que crea la base de datos, actualiza registros o inserta registros nuevos.

Comment: A mi me parece que la razón es que usas un thread java. Un servicio se ejecuta en segundo plano, pero un thread java es para primer plano porque precisamente consume muchos recursos. Por esta razon el servicio consume muchos recursos, yo creo que debes usar un thread android, es decir, un asinktask. Ademas me parece que los conceptos de ciclo de vida de aplicaciones android no estan correctamente aplicados, para ello te recomiendo esta url: http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-fundamentos/37-unidad-6-multimedia-y-ciclo-de-vida/158-ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad

Comment: Tambien recomiendo esta otra url: http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-fundamentos/37-unidad-6-multimedia-y-ciclo-de-vida/489-aplicando-eventos-del-ciclo-de-vida-en-la-actividad-juego-de-asteroides

Comment: @user3737118 podrías agregar ControlNotas()  por favor. =)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @abrahamhs no creo que deberías usar un servicio para consultar y llenar la BD. Los servicios se usan para acciones en el background _a largo plazo_. Te recomendo usar un singleton para tu `ControlNotas` y hacer las llamadas en tu Activity o en tu Presenter, si tienes esa arquitectura

Comment: Además estás invocando la accion a SQL del servicio de manera incorrecta.

Comment: La verdad es que no se usar un Singleton y no tengo un Presenter implantado en mi código. He intentado implantar mi código de otra forma como me ha sugerido abrahamhs, pero el resultado es el mismo. Me consume mucha RAM y el sistema lo echa fuera. Seguiré buscando para ver como implanto el código y reduzco el consumo de RAM. Parecía un simple servicio de notificación, pero se me está complicando y mis conocimientos no dan a más (por ahora).